# Passing data (get/set) between pages

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm looking to do something very simple (or what I perceive as simple).

Basically, I have two pages set up in my XAML/C# UWP app, the first has a series of textboxes and dropdown menus to select options (Name, State, etc).

On the bottom there is a button to go to the next page.

On the next page, I would like to be able to display the user entered data.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this, but after hours of searching, I can't seem to figure out how to pass multiple values between pages. I think I want to create a Class file that stores all of this info, but I'm not exactly sure how to set the values in the C# code from the first page and get the info on the second page.

UPDATE:

So using the answer below I've gotten here:

On the MainPage

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public static  MainPage Current;
    public static string PageOneSelection
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public void changeToNextPage()
    {
        PageToLoad.Navigate(typeof(TwoPlayerGame));
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Current = this;
        PageToLoad.Navigate(typeof(Selection));          

     }

}
```

}

And on the Selection Page:

```
public sealed partial class Selection : Page
{


    new string Name;

    public Selection()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void PlayButton(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MainPage.Current.PageOneSelection = PlayerOneName.Text;
        MainPage.Current.changeToNextPage();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on that class you mentioned, and bind your textboxes etc to these properties, so the data is sync. Then pass this object while navigating to the new page.

Comment: passing multiple values between pages can be done in several ways.. `Session` variables and if it's web based then use `QueryString` if it's a windows app then set some static variables.. INotify

Comment: @adminSoftDK Would you be able to explain this a bit more? Or provide a generic example?

Comment: I can't create an example, as I'm at work atm, also I work with wpf. But you should be able to find lots of info about INotifyPropertyChanged, and also navigation parameters. Hopefully somebody can provide you with an example too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a MainPage which holds all of your pages in Frames.

```
<Page x:Name="Main">
  <Frame x:Name="PageToLoad">
</Page>
```

On the MainPage you have a global which holds "this" and globals to store your selection values from the various pages.

```
public static MainPage Current;
public static string PageOneSelection;
```

And functions to get/store your selections:

```
public string getPageOneSelection()
{
   return PageOneSelection;
}

public void setPageOneSelection(string whatToSetItTo)
{
   PageOneSelection=whatToSetItTo;
}
```

On Initialization

```
// This is a static public property that allows downstream pages to get a handle to the MainPage instance
// in order to call methods that are in this class.
Current = this;
```

On Initialize of the MainPage you should load the first page:

```
PageToLoad.Navigate(/*Your First Page*/);
```

Now whenever they make a selection you can call back and forth to the MainPage to change that selection value

```
//On Page 1
MainPage.Current.setPageOneSelection(theSelectedItem);

//On Page 2
itemFromPage1=MainPage.Current.getPageOneSelection();
```

UPDATE: Your code looks good. So you say you have a textbox you want the information for. You can do this:

```
MainPage.Current.setPageOneSelection(textbox.Text);
```

I'd put this before you navigate to the next frame.

If you have a second selection (ie your dropdown), make another global on your MainPage and do the same thing.

Also if you have can send more than one string at a time, add parameters to your set function:

public void setAllPageOneSelections(string param1, string param2 /*...*/)
   {
     PageOneSelection=param1;
     PageOneSelection2=param2;
   }
In your Main you should probably have a page switcher function. I use:

```
public void changeToNextPage()
{
  PageToLoad.Navigate(/*Page 2 or next page or something */);
}
```

and then for your play button you can do

```
MainPage.Current.changeToNextPage();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sorry to be a pain, but could you explain this a bit more:

"Have functions in your MainPage which store your selection values"

How would I do this exactly?

Comment: @robbiestells what don't you understand?

Comment: Sorry I hit enter to quickly, see the above edited resposne

Comment: @robbiestells actually you don't need that if you have public static global. Use the last part of the answer to get and store the selected items.

Comment: I added the code to the original question, not sure where to put that one piece. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @robbiestells try that, Except, in your play button, you need to call back to the MainPage's Frame. I don't know what the "Frame" you have listed is.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing where the "public static global" goes. I'm trying to put in "MainPage.Current.PageOneSelection=PlayerOneName.Text;" on the Selection page, but it can't reference PageOneSelection

Comment: @robbiestells Oh perhaps it needs a get; set;  Ill make that edit. Try that:

Comment: So here's an interesting development. "MainPage.Current.changeToNextPage();" works and is recognized on the Selection page, but "MainPage.Current.changeToNextPage();" still gives me an error - cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: @robbiestells you mean PageOneSelection? Ok I'd just make that a function too. Ill make the edit

Comment: That was it!!!! Wow, you are the best! I really, really appreciate you taking the time to work this out with me. This is huge. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

use this :-
define this variable:-

```
publicstatic mytextboxinfo {get;set;}
```

and in your function :-

```
submitbutton_Click(){
mytextboxinfo = mytextbox.text; 
}
```

and then in the next page :-

```
Page_loaded() {
mytextbox2.Text = myPage.mytextboxinfo;
}
```

where "myPage" is the name of the page